# Appending Paragraph at specific location

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to be able to change a string of text to heading1 and do some additional formatting later on. Caught up on this part for now. Here is my sample code as of right now.

```
function pocket() {
    // Try to get the current selection in the document. If this fails (e.g.,
    // because nothing is selected), show an alert and exit the function.
    var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    if (!selection) {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a selection in the document.');
        return;
    }
    var selectedElements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    var selectedElement = selectedElements[0];
    var pocketelement = selectedElement.getElement().getText();
    body.appendParagraph(pocketelement).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
}
```

I need it to delete the original string and append the paragraph at the original strings location. Not sure how to do that. any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The body.appendParagraph() method **appends** the given paragraph, like javascript, to the body, at the end of it.

You are looking for the .insertParagraph(index, Paragraph). To get the index, try body.getChildIndex(paragraph). See the code below.

```
function pocket() {
  // Try to get the current selection in the document. If this fails (e.g.,
  // because nothing is selected), show an alert and exit the function.
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = doc.getSelection();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  if (!selection) {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a selection in the document.');
      return;
  }
  var selectedElements = selection.getSelectedElements();
  var selectedElement = selectedElements[0];
  //holds the paragraph
  var paragraph = selectedElement.getElement();
  //get the index of the paragraph in the body
  var paragraphIndex = body.getChildIndex(paragraph);
  //remove the paragraph from the document
  //to use the insertParagraph() method the paragraph to be inserted must be detached from the doc
  paragraph.removeFromParent();
  body.insertParagraph(paragraphIndex, paragraph).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
};
```

Comment: This returns the error "Element does not contain the specified child element." Not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: Nevermind- I was selecting just text. This works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Please, mark the question as Answered so that other people can find the answer more easily :)

Comment: Your comment 'to use the insertParagraph() method the paragraph to be inserted must be detached from the doc' is the light in the darkness. Another use case is to insert a paragraph by deep-copying, eg, `body.insertParagraph(idx, p.copy());`